# If a standard library function is reimplemented, which of the two is called?

Tags: c, unix

If a library function like e.g. `malloc` is reimplemented, then there are two symbols with that name, one in a local object file and one in the system library. Which of the two is used when a function from e.g. `stdio` is used, which calls `malloc` (and why)?

Comment: The traditional model is that modules and libraries later in the linking order override earlier ones, this replacing `malloc` even for internal references. Of course there may easily be complications, such as macro wrappers adding tracing information, or the use of internal variants providing additional hints to the allocator.

Comment: If I understand that right it would mean that usually the system library symbol would be used. But tests show that the local function (the reimplementation) is used instead.

Comment: It is the other way around. The object files are linked in last preceded by the libraries in listing order.

Comment: From own experience I know if a unix-like system is distribution installed and it has its custom optional `libmalloc` and you add a `-lmalloc` flag to your makefile at the end, and `#include <malloc.h>` in your source file, `malloc` from that library would be called instead of `malloc` from `stdlib`, no matter from where within your program. AFAIK, this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link behaviour is, in a general way:

- Include all symbols defined in the object files.
- Then resolve the undefined ones using the objects in the libs.

So, if malloc is reimplemented and linked as object file, the version in the object file will override the version in the standard libraries. However, if the new malloc is linked as a library, it depends on the libraries linking order.

Another way, considering the gnu binutils as scope, to override library functions is to wrap the function using the --wrap parameter: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html

By using the --wrap ld option we can get both functions linked and the wrapper function would be able to call the wrapped one.

The linking order also depends on the command line parameters order. So I'm considering here that libs are listed after objects because, in general, doesn't make sense to put libraries before objects as their objective is to supply the missing symbols demanded by those.

Answer (score -1):

One answer is that you are getting yourself in an awful lot of trouble by trying to replace malloc. Don't go there. Don't even think about it. Especially if you need to ask questions on stackoverflow, don't even think about it.

Another answer is that you are invoking undefined behaviour, and the likely result is that the malloc function will be called that will hurt you most. If you are lucky, while developing. If you are less lucky, once your code is in the hand of customers. Don't do it.

Writing wrappers around malloc with new names is bad enough. Trying to replace malloc is madness.

Comment: There is no real choice, unfortunately. A tool to be ported is using `sbrk` *and* standard library functions. This can't work on today's systems. So either sbrk is replaced (means to rewrite much of the tools code), or a local malloc is provided, which does not use `sbrk`. A problem is left: The local malloc does not work with ASAN, even if that local malloc seems to be correct. Currently it is unclear, why it doesn't work with ASAN.